# Cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type double

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> textdisplay.setText(total.toString());

When i am trying to revoke String. It gives me error like "Cannot invoke tostring() on the primitive type double". I read similar thread and tried everything but nothing works. Strange part is that this same code works for my friend.
Please help.

```
public void showsign(String sign){
        if(last_button==R.id.plus || last_button==R.id.minus || last_button==R.id.multiply 
            || last_button==R.id.divide){

    }
    else{
        clear_flag = 1;
        Double newNumber = Double.parseDouble(textdisplay.getText().toString());
        if(sign_flag == "" || sign_flag == "="){
            total = newNumber;
            textdisplay.setText(total.toString());

        }
        else if(sign_flag == "+"){
            total = total+newNumber;
            textdisplay.setText(total.toString());
        }
        else if(sign_flag == "-"){
            total = total-newNumber;
            textdisplay.setText(total.tostring());
        }
        else if(sign_flag == "*"){
            total = total*newNumber;
            textdisplay.setText(total.tostring());
        }
        else if(sign_flag == "/"){
            total = total/newNumber;
            textdisplay.setText(total.tostring());  
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think the error means? It's pretty clear.

Comment: Also, you'll want to read this: [How do I compare Strings in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: You haven't shown the declaration for total.  I guess it's `double total;`

Comment: Also, you're using the term `revoke` where it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I mean invoke..sorry i am little frustrated.. my whole program is ready except this error.

Comment: my total was declared as double (double total = 0.0;). when i tried using wrapper class (Double total = 0.0;) all errors went away. Thank you all

Answer (score 4):

Primitive types are not `Object`s, and as such don't have `.toString()`.

You have to use (for instance) [`String.valueOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28double%29), ie:

```
textdisplay.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

What is more, this:

```
if(sign_flag == "/")
```

and similar will not work. Use `"/".equals(sign_flag)` instead (or `sign_flag.equals("/")` if `sign_flag` is guaranteed not to be `null`).

Comment: Read the rest of the answer re: string comparison

Comment: The problem is not with the `String`s here.

Comment: @AdamArold not originally, no, but this is another problem in the code, so it might as well be mentioned

Answer (score 2):

You can use String.valueOf(double)

but..

Check out DecimalFormat: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Unlike String.valueOf you can control the amount of decimal digits that you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

A primitive type is not an `Object` therefore it does not have a `toString` method.

I can't see the declaration of `total` but I'm pretty sure that it is a primitive. Try using its wrapper. For example if you see something like `double total =`...
change it to `Double total =`...

The other problem is that if you use `==` it means "compare the references". If you want to compare `Object`s (like a `String`) use the `equals` method.

Comment: I think i wrote double total = 0.0;

Comment: Change it to `Double total = 0.0`

Answer (score 0):

`Double` is the wrapper class for the `double` primitive type.
IF you do not want to *"Auto-box"* doubles into an object, then you can always use: `String.valueOf(double)`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use .toString(), the variable in question must be an Object. Primitives are not objects. To accomplish what you want and what your friend has probably done. You need to use the wrapper class.

Wrapper class:
Double

Primitive:
double

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `textdisplay.setText(total.toString());` use `textdisplay.setText("" + total);`

As others have already pointed out `toString()` method is defined in `Object` class, which is inherited by all `class`es by default, therefore `toString()` method is available for any class you define or available in library. However, primitives like `double`, `int`, `float`, `byte` etc. are not classes therefore the variables of these types cannot call `toString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert the double like this directly you should use this ....

```
    double doublevalue = 0;
    String value = String.valueOf(doublevalue);
```